# Spring Security /AspectJ pointcut

Tags: spring-security, aspectj

Is it possible to protect my @Controller classes using pointcut?  I tried:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <!-- Block anything ending with the word 'Controller'-->
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* my.pkg.*Controller.*(..))" access="NON_EXISTANT_ROLE"/>
</global-method-security>
```

In theory, I should never be able to hit the controller because the role doesn't exist for any user.  However, the controller runs fine.

Comment: Which version of spring security are you using?

Comment: I had that issue before 3.0.5. Also make sure that global-method-security is present in controller context.

Answer (score 0):

See [Spring Security FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context) (emphasis mine).

> In a Spring web application, the application context which holds the
>   Spring MVC beans for the dispatcher servlet is often separate from the
>   main application context. It is often defined in a file called
>   myapp-servlet.xml, where “myapp” is the name assigned to the Spring
>   DispatcherServlet in web.xml. An application can have multiple
>   DispatcherServlets, each with its own isolated application context.
>   The beans in these “child” contexts are not visible to the rest of the
>   application. The “parent” application context is loaded by the
>   ContextLoaderListener you define in your web.xml and is visible to all
>   the child contexts. This parent context is usually where you define
>   your security configuration, including the 
>   element). As a result any security constraints applied to methods in
>   these web beans will not be enforced, since the beans cannot be seen
>   from the DispatcherServlet context. You need to either move the
>    declaration to the web context or moved the
>   beans you want secured into the main application context.
>
> **Generally we would recommend applying method security at the service
>   layer rather than on individual web controllers.**

If you apply pointcuts to service layer you only need to set `<global-method-security>` in your app's security context.